# How to control 2 micro magnetic actuators with esp12e

Tags: esp8266, wifi, servo, h-bridge, l293d

i want to control two micro magnetic actuators (just two coil where I want to flow current in +to- and-to+ each motor for wifi airplane) with esp12e
Do I need an h-bridge like l293d ?
Also I will be using mit app inventor any advice for it will nice:)))

Comment: Yes you need an H-bridge. "Any advice" is rather broad. This site works best for more narrow questions

Comment: Alternatively you can get by with half an H bridge but will need a power supply which can deliver positive, ground and negative voltages.  Your choice.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I noticed that l293d works on min.4.5v but I can provide 3.3v or 4v only:((